# Route Differentiation between Admin & Non-Admin in Laravel

Tags: regex, laravel, vue.js

I am building an SPA using Laravel & Vue. I want two different routes for admin & non-admin users like this.

```
// For Admin
Route::any('admin/{any}', static function () {
    return view('admin');
})->name('admin')->where('any', '.*');

// For Non-Admin
Route::any('{any}', static function () {
    return view('app');
})->name('app')->where('any', '.*');
```

All is working fine for Non-Admin routes but when I go to admin routes it gives this error:
[image: Access Forbidden!]

I think I am not able to set the regex correctly or some other error which I can't troubleshoot.

Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: Is this hosted on a server or locally?

Comment: it is running locally

Answer (score 0):

Try these routes

```
Route::get('/admin/{any?}', function () {
    return view('admin');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');

Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```